# What is the best way to export upto 1 million records into excel sheet via REST call?

Tags: java, excel, performance, rest, time

I have a table that contains millions of data and whenever user wants to export the data into an excel sheet it's taking more time when the respective table contains huge data which leads to a longer time to wait for the user.
Here data exported by using java Apache POI.

My question here is that Is there any best way to export the entire data in a shorter time than expected?

Do we have any optimization techniques by using multi-threading, streaming, process and download later kind of thing.

Appreciated for any suggestions.

Comment: Need more details. Is the client app a web site or desktop app? Also, do you have control over the app that is uploading the data, i.e, you are the developer of the app?

Comment: @AndroidDev Yes. I am developing the application and it is a web site. The data will be filled by different users and grows up very fast so when a particular user tries to download the data then it's taking more time. Is there any best way to download it faster?

Answer (score 0):

What workbook are you using in export HSSF Workbook or SXSSF Workbook

If not SXSSF, try once.

You can get more info [here](https://programming.vip/docs/solution-of-exporting-million-level-data-to-excel-using-poi.html).

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Jasinder Singh. Approximately how much time it will take to download  1 million records with 46 columns or in other words what is the time difference between HSSF and SXSSF Workbook?